# Entry string not being added to listbox

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter

Could anyone help me debug this? The listbox isn't updating, and I'm not sure if the entry text (`ment`) is even transferring to the method.

```
def NewTask():
    ment = StringVar()
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("Add New Task")
    top.minsize(300,300)
    top.maxsize(300,300)

    label_newtask = Label(top, text = "Entry New Task:", font = ("Purisa",20))
    label_newtask.pack()


    button_newtask = Button(top, text="Enter", command= NewTaskCount)
    button_newtask.pack()

    entry_newtask = Entry(top, textvariable=ment)
    entry_newtask.pack()



def NewTaskCount():
    ment = StringVar()
    mtext = ment.get()
    listbox.insert(END, mtext)
    return
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether listbox can be updated 'on the go'

Comment: @AlokChaudhary: yes, of course it can.

Comment: can dropdowns also be updated? because i tried them once & they didnt...

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your stringvar `ment` is a local variable that is only visible within the scope of `NewTask`. In NewTaskCount, you are creating a *new* StringVar -- which is initially blank -- and immediately getting the value of that new variable. You need to make it a global variable, or use an object-oriented approach so that you can use an instance variable.

Comment: How would I go about making it a global variable?

Comment: @user1840752 put `ment = StringVar()` before functions and replace
`ment = StringVar()` with `global ment` in both functions.